# Why the child process terminated ?? please explain me?

Tags: c, unix

I  work with the tcsetpgrp() function, i run this code in gcc complier. I want to change the STDOUT_FILENO to a new group, which was created by the child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf("Parent pgid=%d\n", getpgrp());
  printf("STDOUT(parent)=%d\n", tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO));
  pid_t pid;
  if(0 == (pid = fork()))
    {
      setpgid(0, 0);     
      printf("child pgid=%d\n", getpgrp());
      if(0 != tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO, 0))
        perror("Error");
      printf("After changing %d\n", tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO));
      exit(0);
    }
  wait(0);
  return 0;
}
```

in that child process when the tcsetpgrp() function reaches the child process terminated and the exit status doesn't report to parent.

Comment: btw what were you trying to achieve :) ?

Comment: I think you are ignoring this " If setpgid() is used to move a process
       from one process group to another (as is done by some shells when
       creating pipelines), both process groups must be part of the same
       session (see setsid(2) and credentials(7))."

Comment: Yeah, you probably have to call `setsid`

Comment: @KCdod I want to change the `STDOUT_FILENO` to a new group, which was created by the child process.

Comment: just asking, have you tried using pipes to inter process communication :) ?

Answer (score 2):

When the child process calls `tcsetpgrp`, it receives the `SIGTTOU` signal, which causes it to stop.  As the child process is stopped, the parent process blocks in the call to `wait`, waiting for the child to terminate.

The simple solution would be to ignore the `SIGTTOU` signal in the child, just after the call to `fork`:

```
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN)
```

There is another issue with your code — you're trying to change the terminal's process group to 0, which doesn't make any sense.  You probably wanted to say:

```
tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO, getpgrp())
```